# Elastic Beanstalk terminates my EC2 instance

Tags: amazon-web-services, iis, amazon-ec2, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, terminate

I deploy my ASP.NET web site to ec2 instance via Elastic Beanstalk. When I test my site (upload file of 23 megabytes in size) Elastic Beanstalk terminate the instance. A problem in that on ec2 instance I must to use some externall dlls and licenses for their. But after terminating they are removed. How can I configure Elastic Beanstalk do not terminate instance?

Comment: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/autoscaling/latest/userguide/as-instance-termination.html

Answer (score 0):

First, if it is terminating the instance when you upload a large file it is because some error is occurring on the server causing it to fail status checks. You need to look at the server logs to determine what the issue is and work on that.

Second, if you are manually copying licensed files to Elastic Beanstalk instances and any auto-scaling event in Elastic Beanstalk is breaking your application then Elastic Beanstalk is not a good fit for your application. You should probably be using a plain EC2 server isntead of Elastic Beanstalk.